# How to find faulty data and replace it.? plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a faulty record in History_TABLE with `book_id=001`.. 
`book_id=005` should have been with `motif_histo=D` at row 4. but i have `book_id=001` at row 4.

I want to find out how many roll_no's have this faulty records. and how can i change it using pls/sql

```
Table: History_TABLE
Roll_No | Book_id | Book | Name | Motif_histo | Date     |
1       | 001     | Georg| AWT  |  c          |20/03/2019|
1       | 001     | Georg| AWT  |  D          |20/03/2019|
1       | 001     | Georg| AWT  |  c          |11/12/2018|
1       | 001     | Georg| AWT  |  D          |11/12/2018|
1       | 005     | clone| JSP  |  C          |19/01/2018|

TABLE: MAIN_TABLE
Roll_No | Book_id | Book | Name | Motif_histo | Date     |
1       | 001     | Georg| AWT  |  c          |20/03/2019|
```

FYI: the MAIN_TABLE book_id should be equal to book_id from History_TABLE having max(date)

Comment: the tag and title `plsql` suggests you are using PostgreSQL as RDMS and not MySQL ...  Can you check which RDMS you are using and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58788672/how-to-find-faulty-data-and-replace-it-plsql) the question to have the correct tagging, for now i have removed the conflicting MySQL and `plsql` tags from the question..

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  I see `motif_histo=D` on line 4.  Can you provide a better explanation of what "faulty" means?  Does it somehow related to `main_table`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  MOTIF_HISTO=D must be for book_id=005.. as i am deleting the old entry and putting a new entry with book_id=001

Comment: Vote it to close as "unclear what you are asking" .. please share the expected output then i will retract my vote.

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and include the results you expect. The explanations you've given are not clear - including the expected results would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that rows with `Motif_histo = 'D'` should have `Book_id = 5` then we have the following. However, your last comment about "deleting the old entry and putting a new entry with book_id=001" is a bit confusing":

If you want to know how many "faulty" rows you have, then run the following query:

```
select count(*) from History_TABLE where Motif_histo = 'D' and Book_id <> '005';
```

To correct these rows, run the following:

```
update History_TABLE set Book_id = '005' where Motif_histo = 'D' and Book_id <> '005';
```

Comment: the book_id can be different.

Comment: @AK Then I don't understand your question (and I don't even really understand your comment) and the lack of responses may indicate that I am not alone. Perhaps you can update your question and try to be a little clearer as to what is "faulty", i.e. what needs to change. Thanks in advance.

Comment: whenever an entry is made in main table it gets saved in history table.. The second time u make entry in main table the history table deletes the old record and enters new records with motif_histo as C. but in my case wrong entry was made in history table.. the second last row must contain the record of last row with motif_histo as D

Comment: I am sorry but `The second time u make entry in main table the history table deletes the old record and enters new records with motif_histo as C.` is not clear and seems to conflict with the previous statement `whenever an entry is made in main table it gets saved in history table`. What even distinguishes the first time from the second time?